How to upgrade django version of a project?
My project is running on Django 1.10 version.
And I am using postgres as my DB. As Postgres has newer versions and older version is depricated, AWS is charging more for database support.
So, I have to update Postgres version 16. As Django 1.10 does not have support for Postgres 16. I am planning to upgrade to Django 4.2 LTS.
How can I upgrade my Django and what things should I consider (change functions or models etc.) after I install the 4.2 version of Django?

"What things should I consider (change functions or models etc.) after I install the 4.2 version of Django?" - Start by reading this:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/upgrade-version/.
